# sqlalchemy automatically extend query or update or insert upon table definition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

in my app I have a mixin that defines 2 fields like start_date and end_date. I've added this mixin to all table declarations which require these fields.

I've also defined a function that returns filters (conditions) to test a timestamp (e.g. now) to be >= start_date and < end_date. Currently I'm manually adding these filters whenever I need to query a table with these fields.

However sometimes me or my colleagues forget to add the filters, and I wonder whether it is possible to automatically extend any query on such a table. Like e.g. an additional function in the mixin that is invoked by SQLalchemy whenever it "compiles" the statement. I'm using 'compile' only as an example here, actually I don't know when or how to best do that.

Any idea how to achieve this?

In case it works for SELECT, does it also work for INSERT and UPDATE?

thanks a lot for your help

Juergen

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [example](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/PreFilteredQuery).  You can change the criteria expressed in the private method to refer to your start and end dates.
Note that this query will be less efficient because it overrides the get method to bypass the identity map.
I'm not sure what the `enable_assertions` false call does; I'd recommend understanding that before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

I tried extending Query but had a hard time. Eventually (and unfortunately) I moved back to my previous approach of little helper functions returning filters and applying them to queries.

I still wish I would find an approach that automatically adds certain filters if a table (Base) has certain columns.

Juergen